# Filter dates in R with dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a large dataset (> 3k rows) that I want to filter based on geographic location and date. The location filtering works fine but I get the following error message when using logical operators on Dates with `filter` (`dplyr`):

```
Error: level sets of factors are different
```

my current codes is as below:

```
head(master.data)
   State.Name County.Code Latitude Longitude Arithmetic.Mean Date.Local
1     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             8.0 2014-01-02
2     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             7.0 2014-01-05
3     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             7.0 2014-01-08
4     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             3.6 2014-01-11
5     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             5.2 2014-01-14
6     Alabama           3 30.49748 -87.88026             4.4 2014-01-17  

master.data$Date.Local <- as.Date(master.data$Date.Local, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

site.info <- data.frame("Alabama", 3, 30, 90, "28/12/2015", "13/07/2016")
names(site.info) <- c("State.Name", "County.Code", "Latitude", "Longitude", 
                       "Date.Start", "Date.End")
site.info$Date.Start <- as.Date(site.info$Date.Start, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
site.info$Date.End <- as.Date(site.info$Date.End, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

reduced.data <- filter(master.data, State.Name == site.info$State.Name, 
                       Date.Local >= site.info$Date.Start 
                       & Date.Local <= site.info$Date.End)
```

Both `site.info` and `master.data` have the dates formatted using `as.Date`. The input format is different because they are imported from external sources.

I am able to perform logical operations on the two with the expected results outside of `filter`. Not sure why this is the case. Using `%in%` yields the same results

```
Date.Local %in% c(site.info$Date.Start, site.info$Date.End)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I think your `State.Name == site.info$State.Name` may be troubling if there are more number of elements in 'site.info' and is `factor` class.  You may try a `join`.  This can be done more easily with `data.table` i.e. `setDT(master.data)[site.info, on = .(State.Name, Date.Local >= Date.Start, Date.Local <=Date.End)]`

Comment: I'll try this too. `site.info` has no more than 12 rows and the dates are formatted using `as.Date` so I'm curious as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your State.Name column is probably a factor - with different levels in each data.frame. If you include `dput(head(master.data))` in you question we can know for certain. Unless you want this column as a factor, don't let it become one. EG use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table`

Comment: @Richard You are correct, `State.Name` is indeed a factor. The output is too long to print here. Others are `int' or `num` except for `Date.Local` which is a `date`

Comment: Tried using both methods but it doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying, it seems that `subset` works better than `filter` in this case:

```
 reduced.data <- subset(master.data, Latitude %in% closest.sites$Latitude
                        & Longitude %in% closest.sites$Longitude
                        & Date.Local >= site.info$Date.Start 
                        & Date.Local <= site.info$Date.End)
```

The above code gives me exactly the results I want.

Now I am stuck trying to filter all entries with the same time stamp - I want to filter all samples taken on the same day and find the average. Both `subset` and `filter` seem to fail in this case. R is woe.